# Conditional substitution of patterns in bash strings depending on the beginning of a string

Tags: sed

I am new in bash, so excuse me if do not use the right terms.

I need to substitute certain patterns of six characters in a set of files. The order by patterns are substituted depends on the beginning of each string of text.

This is an example of input:

```
chr1:123-123 5GGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTA3

chr1:456-456 5TTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGG3 

chr1:789-789 5GGGCTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTA3
```

`chr1:123-123` etc is the name of the string, they are separated from the string I need to work with by a tab. The string I need to work with is delimited by characters 5 and 3, but I can change them.

I want that all patterns containing `T`, `A`, `G` in anyone of these orders is substituted with `X`: `TTAGGG`, `TAGGG`, `AGGGTT`, `GGGTTA`, `GGTTAG`, `GTTAGG`.

Similarly, patterns containing `CTAGGG`, like row 3, in orders similar to the previous one will be substituted with a different character.
The game is repeated with some specific differences for all the 6 characters composing each pattern.
I started writing something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
NORMAL=`echo "\033[m"`
RED=`echo "\033[31m"` #red

#read filename for the input file and create a copy and a folder for the output
read -p "Insert name for INPUT file: " INPUT
echo "Creating OUTPUT file " "${RED}"$INPUT"_sub.txt${NORMAL}"
mkdir -p ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT
cp $INPUT.txt ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
echo 
#start the first set of instructions
perfrep
#starting a second set of instructions to substitute pattern with one difference from TTAGGG
onemism
```

Instructions are

```
perfrep() {
    sed -i -e 's/TTAGGG/X/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
    sed -i -e 's/TAGGGT/X/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
    sed -i -e 's/AGGGTT/X/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt 
    sed -i -e 's/GGGTTA/X/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt     
    sed -i -e 's/GGTTAG/X/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt     
    sed -i -e 's/GTTAGG/X/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
}

# starting a second set of instructions to substitute pattern with one difference from TTAGGG
onemism(){
    sed -i -e 's/[GCA]TAGGG/L/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
    sed -i -e 's/G[GCA]TAGG/L/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
    sed -i -e 's/GG[GCA]TAG/L/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
    sed -i -e 's/GGG[GCA]TA/L/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
    sed -i -e 's/AGGG[GCA]T/L/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
    sed -i -e 's/TAGGG[GCA]/L/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
}
```

I will need to repeat also with `T[GCA]AGGG`, `TT[TCG]GGG`, `TTA[ACT]GG`, `TTAG[ACT]G` and `TTAGG[ACT]`.

Using this procedure, I get for these results for the inputs shown

```
5GGGXXXXTTA3

5XXXXX3 

5GGGLXXTTA3
```

In my point of view, for my job, the first and second string are both made by X repeated five times, and the order of characters is just slightly different. On the other hand, the third one could be masked like this:

```
5LXXX3
```

How do I tell the script that if the string starts with 5GGGTTA instead of 5TTAGGG must start to substitute with

```
sed -i -e 's/GGGTTA/X/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
```

instead of

```
sed -i -e 's/TTAGGG/X/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
```

?

I will need to repeat with all cases; for instance, if the string starts with GTTAGG I will need to start with

```
sed -i -e 's/GTTAGG/X/g' ./"$INPUT"_OUTPUT/"$INPUT"_sub.txt
```

and so on, and add a couple of variation of my pattern.

I need to repeat the substitution with `TTAGGG` and the variations for all the rows of my input file.

Sorry for the very long question. Thank you all.

Adding information asked by Varun.

Patterns of 6 characters would be `TTAGGG` , `[GCA]TAGGG` , `T[GCA]AGGG` , `TT[TCG]GGG` , `TTA[ACT]GG` , `TTAG[ACT]G` , `TTAGG[ACT]`.
Each one must be checked for a different frame, for instance for `TTAGGG` we have 6 frames `TTAGGG` , `GTTAGG` , `GGTTAG`, `GGGTTA` , `AGGGTT` , `TAGGGT`.
The same frames must be applied to the pattern containing a variable position.

I will have a total of 42 patterns to check, divided in 7 groups: one containing `TTAGGG` and derivative frames, 6 with the patterns with a variable position and their derivatives.
`TTAGGG` and derivatives are the most important and need to be checked first.

Comment: once you start backtracking (changing the order in which rules are applied)  you are pushing what should be done with regular expressions in sed which is best at a single pass over a stream . also AGGG does not make sense to me above

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, there's no need (usually) to run multiple sed instances on the same file as you have done above. Given largeish files, you can significantly reduce your run-time by "chaining" multiple substitutions inside one call to sed, i.e. `sed -i 's/TTAGGG/X/g;s/TAGGGT/X/g;s/AGGGTT/X/g;...' file`. (And `-e` is usually not needed). Good luck.

Comment: @tomc, thank you for your comment. This one is a very raw version of the script, I would have optimize later. Plus, having just started working with bash, I know nothing about rules or best solutions for commands. AGGG was a mistake, it should have been AGGGTT.

Comment: @shellter thank you for the correction concerning multiple instances.

Comment: OK, as is, there is too much info your Q (IMHO ;-). Boil this down to one issue, with one block of code. Get that to work, it may give you insight to solving others, OR if you're stuck, then post another, small(er) Q. repeat as needed. Or work thru the `sed` tutorial at http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html. Also agree with tomc's comment, sed is probably not your end-game tool set. Good luck.

Comment: Not part of your answer, but general advice for shell scripting: don't embed terminal codes `NORMAL=$(echo "\033[m")` but instead prefer to obtain the [correct codes for the terminal in question](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037) `NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)` and `RED==$(tput setaf 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

# generate a "frame" by moving the first char to the end
function rotate(base){ return substr(base,2) substr(base,1,1) }

# Unfortunately awk arrays do not store regexps 
# so I am generating the list of derivative strings to match
function generate_derivative(frame,arr,  i,j,k,head,read,tail) {
    arr[i]=frame;
    for(j=1; j<=length(frame); j++) {
        head=substr(frame,1,j-1);
        read=substr(frame,j,1);
        tail=substr(frame,j+1);
        for( k=1; k<=3; k++) {
           # use a global index to simplify
            arr[++Z]= head substr(snp[read],k,1) tail
        }
    }
}

BEGIN{
    fs="\t";
   # alternatives to a base
   snp["A"]="TCG"; snp["T"]="ACG"; snp["G"]="ATC";  snp["C"]="ATG"; 

    # the primary target
    frame="TTAGGG";
    Z=1; # warning GLOBAL
    X[Z] = frame;
    # primary derivatives
    generate_derivative(frame, X);
    xn = Z;

    # secondary shifted targets and their derivatives
    for(i=1; i<length(frame); i++){
        frame = rotate(frame);
        L[++Z] = frame;
        generate_derivative(frame, L);
    }
}

/^chr[0-9:-]*\t5[ACTG]*3$/ {

    # because we care about the order of the prinary matches
    for (i=1; i<=xn; i++) {gsub(X[i],"X",$2)}
    # since we don't care about the order of the secondary matches
    for (hit in L) {gsub(L[hit],"L",$2)}
    print
}
END{
    # print the matches in the order they are generated
    #for (i=1; i<=xn; i++) {print X[i]};
    #print ""
    #for (i=1+xn; i<=Z; i++) {print L[i]};
}
```

IFF you can generate a static matching order you can live with then 
something like the above Awk script could work. but you say the primary patterns should take precedence and that a secondary rule would  be better applied first in some cases. (no can do).

If you need a more flexible matching pattern I would suggest looking at "recursive decent parsing with backtracking" Or "parsing expression grammars".
But then you are not in a bash shell anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the code. In the end, before reading your answer, I was able to run a script with a lot of conditional statements for the frame and multiple sed with patterns I wrote by hand. It seems it works, but it is very slow and it is not able to substitute correctly when insertions change the frame of the sequence... Beside being a very long script. I will try to post part of the code somewhere.